# Averaging over loss values in training of ANNs

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions

I am training my neural network with simple SGD and I am wondering, what is the correct way to plot the loss function? I have this result

[image: Plot]

The averaged loss (over 5 epochs) is less spikey and easier to read trends from. However am I missing some possible information, should I use only average values? Or is the averaging ever used at all?